# Read each line from a file, creating ints from it

Tags: java, input

I have a file called membercodes.cfg.
I want to read each line (lines are like this: 555:333:989) to be read.
Then, the line must be split in 3 parts.
Integer 1 must be valued 555, Integer 2 valued 333, and Integer 3 valued 989.

Thank you all.

Comment: I tried almost everything, but I am pretty new to java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many programming tasks, this is really a matter of splitting one "big" task into small ones:

- Work out how to read a file a line at a time (look at `FileInputStream`, `InputStreamReader`, `BufferedReader`, and `BufferedReader.readLine`; avoid FileReader, which *always* uses the platform default character encoding - a bad idea)
- Work out how to split a line into different strings based on a delimiter (look at `String.split`)
- Work out how to parse a String into an int (look at `Integer.parseInt`)

As another answer points out, there's also `Scanner`. My own experience with `Scanner` has been somewhat limited, but it sometimes feels a bit too much like black magic which is hard to debug when things don't go as planned. On the other hand, it may well end up with less code.

Whichever solution you end up using, you should probably look at *both* of them... aside from anything else, it's a useful exercise to break up the big task as I've done, and it's also a good idea to learn the various bits of the Java API - both the "low-level" APIs such as the ones I've mentioned, and the higher-level ones like `Scanner`.

Comment: Hello Jon Skeet.
I tried part one, but then the line is equivalent to "333:444:555" and when I do if(line == "333:444:555"){SYstem.out.println("true")}

It doesnt even display true!

Comment: @StackExceptionE: No, it wouldn't - because you're using "==" to compare strings... that will only compare string *references* rather than the *values* within the strings. Try using `equals` instead.

Comment: Hm. I still can't get it to work. Im very new to Java and also to IO so I don't know how I can get this to work... Maybe someone has a little example?

Comment: @StackExceptionE: I suggest you ask a separate question for the bit of it that you can't get to work. You should be able to work out which part isn't working, and ask a question specific to that, without reference to the rest. It's very important to be able to focus on one particular small task.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, I shall try doing that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you very much. I tried the scanner, and it works exactly how I need it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) ?

Comment: Can I use the following code for reading it?

Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test.txt"));
      while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
          long aLong = sc.nextLong();
      }

Im very new to java IO so I dont know very much.

Comment: You can find examples here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Scanner.htm .